# static_cast from char to enum assigning wrong value

Tags: c++, enums, static-cast

I can't figure out why my code is returning the wrong value.  input of 'a' returns 97 and 'z'returns 122.  What am i doing missing?

```
  int main()
  {
enum Alphabet {a = 1, b = 2, c = 3,d = 4,e = 5,f = 6,g = 7,h = 8,i = 9,j = 10,k =     11,l = 12,m = 13,n = 14,o = 15,p = 16,q = 17,r = 18,s = 19,t = 20,u = 21,v = 22,w = 23,x =     24,y = 25,z = 26 };
int jon;
char input;
cout << "Enter a letter and I will tell you it's position in the alphabet ";
cin >> input;
while (!isalpha(input))
{
    cout << "Try Again.  Enter a letter and I will tell you it's position";
    cin >> input;
}
Alphabet inputEnum = static_cast<Alphabet>(input);
cout<<inputEnum;
cin>>jon;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: [http://www.asciitable.com/](http://www.asciitable.com/)

Comment: It has to use an enum and I don't want to write a case statement for all the values in the enum

Comment: If it "has to" use enum, then you've described the problem wrong.  Because the problem you've described *cannot* be solved by an enum.

Answer (score 1):

Enums associate compile time identifiers (such as `a`, `b`, and `c`) to integer values.  They don't associate run time `char` values (such as `'a'`, `'b'`, `'c'`, note the quote marks) to integers.  They already are integers, and their values are determined by the character set your implementation is using.  Pretty much every implementation uses ASCII, or something compatible with ASCII, which explains the values you are getting.  It seems that what you want instead is a map:

```
std::map<char,int> alphabet;
alphabet['a'] = 1;
alphabet['b'] = 2;
etc...
```

Or perhaps a simple function:

```
int alphabet(char c)
{
    switch(c)
    {
        case 'a': return 1;
        case 'b': return 2;
        etc...
    }
}
```

If you want to assume the character set is ASCII, or ASCII compatible (a fairly safe assumption), then your function can be simpler:

```
int alphabet(char c)
{
    if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')
        return c - 'a' + 1;
    else
        // c is not a lowercase letter
        // handle it somehow
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, a char (like your `input` variable) is really just an integer value. When associated with letters, like `a`, they go by ASCII value. The ASCII value for `a` is 97, for `b` it's 98, and so on.

A much simpler way to get what you're after is:

```
int inputPosition = input - 'a' + 1;
cout << inputPosition;
```

Answer (score 0):

While an old question, I thought I might just note this down in case others want a way to do something similar to the OP.

I ran into the same problem, but like the OP, I did not want to sit there, and fill out a long 26 case switch block. So instead I figured out a better, time sparing way of doing it:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string>

// Takes in a alphabetic char, and returns 
// the place of the letter in the aplhabet as an int.
int AlphabetCode(char _char){
    // Used to compare against _char.
    char tempChar = 'A';
    // Cycle through the alphabet until we find a match.
    for (int cnt = 1; cnt < 26; cnt++) {
        if (tempChar == toupper(_char)) {
            return cnt;
        }
        else {
            // Increment tempChar.
            // eg: A becomes B, B becomes C etc.
            tempChar++;
        }
    }
}
```